# Hibernate update does not work

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, rollback

I have SpringMVC/Hibernate web application. When I try to update one of the entries nothing happens. 
I try to update the entry using :`org.hibernate.Session.merge(object)` 
I don't have any exceptions.
I enabled mysql to log all the request that receives, In the log I found that there is the update statement but right after that there is a `rollback` which obviously cancels the update. This is the mysql log

`168 Query     SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
 168 Query     SET autocommit=0
 156 Query     SET autocommit=0
 156 Query     select tasks0_.id as id1_0_0_, tasks0_.assigneeId as assignee7_0_0_, tasks0_.description as descript2_0_0_, tasks0_.dueDate as dueDate3_0_0_, tasks0_.name as name4_0_0_, tasks0_.shortName as shortNam5_0_0_, tasks0_.status as status6_0_0_ from tasks tasks0_ where tasks0_.id=2
 156 Query     select user0_.id as id1_1_0_, user0_.email as email2_1_0_, user0_.fullName as fullName3_1_0_, user0_.password as password4_1_0_, user0_.username as username5_1_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=1
 156 Query     update tasks set assigneeId=1, description='task1 desc', dueDate='2012-01-01', name='nameaddsaqqq1111111', shortName='task 1 shrt name', status='READY' where id=2
 156 Query     rollback
 156 Query     SET autocommit=1
 168 Query     commit
 168 Query     SET autocommit=1`

I don't know what might cause the rollback. Does anyone have an idea?

The code of the controller :

```
@Controller
public class TaskController {

@Autowired
private TasksService tasksService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/task/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editTask(@Valid Tasks task, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm");
        } else {
            Tasks t = tasksService.findTaskById(task.getId());
            update(task, t);
            t.setName("addsaasddsa");

            tasksService.update(t);
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("task/editOrCreate");
            modelAndView.addObject("task",
                    tasksService.findTaskById(task.getId()));
            return modelAndView;

        }
    }
```

The code of the service :

```
public interface TasksService {

    public void update(Tasks task);

}
```

The code of the service implementation :

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class TasksServiceImpl implements TasksService {

    @Autowired
    TaskDAO taskDao;


    @Override
    public void update(Tasks task) {
        taskDao.updates(task);
    }

}
```

The code of the DAO:

```
public interface TaskDAO {

    public void updates(Tasks task);

}
```

The code of DAO implementation :

```
@Repository
public class TaskDAOImpl extends DbDaoImpl<Tasks> implements TaskDAO {


    @Override
    public void updates(Tasks task) {
        update(task);
    }
}
```

The code of DbDaoImpl :

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public abstract class DbDaoImpl<T> implements Dao<T> {

@Autowired
    private SessionFactory factory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return factory.getCurrentSession();
    }

@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T update(final T entity) {
        return (T) getSession().merge(entity);
    }
}


public interface Dao<T> extends Serializable {

    T update(final T entity);
}
```

The hibernate configuration properties :

```
dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/qwerty
dataSource.username=root
dataSource.password=root

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

The code of the JPA configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.task.tracker.DAO", "my.pack" } /*
                                                                             * basePackageClasses
                                                                             * =
                                                                             * Application
                                                                             * .
                                                                             * class
                                                                             */)
class JpaConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${dataSource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${dataSource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${dataSource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    private static final String HIBERNATE_CONFIGURATION_FILE = "hibernate.properties";


    @Bean
    public DataSource configureDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource config = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setUrl(url);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);

        config.setConnectionProperties(hibernateConfiguration());

        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("my.pack",
                "com.task.tracker.DAO");
        entityManagerFactoryBean
                .setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    // @Qualifier(value = ComponentName.BEAN_SESSION_FACTORY)
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        localSessionFactoryBean
                .setHibernateProperties(hibernateConfiguration());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages(new String[] { "my.pack",
                "com.task.tracker.DAO" });
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("my.pack",
                "com.task.tracker.DAO");

        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the hibernate properties from the <b>hibernate.properties</b>
     * configuration file.
     * 
     * @return The {@link Properties} object holding all hibernate
     *         configurations.
     */
    @Bean
    // @Qualifier(value = ComponentName.HIBERNATE_PROPERTIES)
    public Properties hibernateConfiguration() {
        final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        final URL url = loader.getResource(HIBERNATE_CONFIGURATION_FILE);
        final Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            properties.load(url.openStream());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("sfdsfsdf");
        }

        return properties;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager getTransMang() {
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager tr = new org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager(
                sessionFactory().getObject());
        return tr;
    }

}
```

The code of the security config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        return new UserService();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        return new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember-me-key",
                userService());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.eraseCredentials(true).userDetailsService(userService());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/signup")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin").permitAll().failureUrl("/signin?error=1")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate").and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/signin?logout").and().rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                .key("remember-me-key");
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

The application configuration :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.task.tracker.services", "com.task.tracker.DAO.impl" }, excludeFilters = @Filter({
        Controller.class, Configuration.class }))
class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/persistence.properties"));
        return ppc;
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably related to the phase of the moon, or maybe the weather, or, who knows... the code?

Comment: Without our code one can only guess, but the what you descibed sounds like you only a read only transaction. (add `@Transactional` at your controller method and check if this helps.)

Comment: I have added the code. I have the @Transactional annotation in the service layer but it doesn't help.

Comment: Could you also publish your spring config ? Have declared a TransactionManager ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `JpaConfig`I have two beans returning `PlatformTransactionManager` one that returns `JpaTransactionManager` and one that returns `HibernateTransactionManager`. The solution is to remove the `JpaTransactionManager`.

Thanks to everyone who commented on the question.